# truffle init Error making request. Please check the format of the requested resource

Tags: powershell, truffle

How can I resolve this for truffle@4.0.1?
I am running 'truffle init' in Windows PowerShell as an Admin and I am receiving this error.  If I try to go to the url in the browser it gives me I see an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET page.

```
PS C:\Users\UserName\desktop\Demo> truffle init
Downloading...
Error: Error making request. Please check the format of the requested resource: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/truffle-box/bare-box/master/truffle.js
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\zswann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:311386:23)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\zswann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:283165:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\zswann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:283857:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and figured out that my browser blocking the URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com

Once my admin unblock the URL and it's working fine.